# Form submits twice when pressing return/enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm using anchors as links, and also I'm binding the enter/return key to submit a form, like this:

```
$("form[name!=smsform]").bind("keyup", function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 13){
$(this).submit();
});

$("a[title=submit]").click( function(){
$(this).parents("form").submit();
});
```

However the form submits twice when clicking enter/return using the code above, I need to merge the two snippets - anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: this thread is weird all the answer say prevent but no one give a codes or tell us how to prevent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A form will submit automatically when you click enter, there is no need to write the code yourself. If you want to add some testing to the enterkey event before you submit, then you can return false from the callback function to prevent the default browser action.

Answer (score 3):

Usually this means that both your link *and* the browser's default mechanism are submitting the form. To prevent that, put a handler on the form's `submit` event that prevents (stops) it (the event is not fired when you submit the form programmatically, so it won't prevent your link sending it).

For example:

```
document.querySelector("selector-for-your-form").addEventHandler("submit", event => {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevents submission
});
```

Comment: any snippet codes or example for this?

Comment: @buncis - I've added one.

Answer (score 2):

Try preventing the default action of the enter key before calling the submit.