# why form submit more than one time with one time press enter key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am a developer but I am facing a problem with form submissions with ajax request. I am developing a post comment system in which many posts are displayed on a page wall. We can comment on any post. I have implemented pagination on wall post in which onscroll post is loaded dynamically.

When posts are loaded dynamically, if any one wants to comment on these post, the comment is being submitted generally more than once.

Why is the comment form being submit more than once when I press enter only one time?

My form ajax script file, named wallPartial.js:

```
if(I != "" && supper_comment_text != "")
    {
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: siteUrl+"waller/saveSupperCommentCL",
            cache: false ,
            async : false ,
            crossDomain: false,
            data: {'post_id' : I, 'supper_comment_text' : supper_comment_text},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(ksb)
            { 
               if(ksb.status=="Success")
                { console.log('my message-1'); 
                    $.ajax({
                           type:"GET",
                           url: siteUrl+"waller/dynRefreshSupperCommentsCL",
                           data: {'post_id' : I},
                           contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                           success: function(ksb_comments_details)
                           {
                               $('#supper-comment-editor'+I).val('');
                               $('li').remove('#UFIRow-CH'+I);
                               $('#supper-comment-li'+I).before(ksb_comments_details);
                               $('#UFIRow-CommetedH'+I).hide();
                           }
                        });
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(ksb.msg);
                }

            }
        });
    }
    return false;
```

I want to confirm one more this that above script is being loaded many times by wall pagination and wall pagination code is -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function last_post_funtion() 
    { 
       var baseUrl = $('#baseUrl').val();
       var siteUrl = $('#siteUrl').val();
       var act="get";
       var ID=$(".postHolder:last").attr("id");

        $.ajax({
               type:   'POST',
               async:   false ,
               url :   siteUrl+'pagination/load_wall_paginationCL',
               data:   { 'action':act, 'last_post_id':ID },
               success: function(data) {
                                        if (data != "") {
                                        $(".postHolder:last").after(data);  
                                        if(window.foo == false){
                                        $.getScript(baseUrl+"/js/wallPartial.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr){
                                        console.log('Script loaded');
                                        window.foo = false;
                                                                                                                   });
                                                                }
                                        }
                                        }
               });

    };  

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
           last_post_funtion();
        }
    });         
});
```

Comment: i would look into promises

Comment: @ Daniel A. White, I could not get your point

Comment: i am not sure but i noticed two things: 1st you are using GET and not POST , i really wounder why...Second where is the code that catch the ENTER key?

Comment: @ stackunderflow, This script is loaded many time dynamically on wall when pagination js script is run by scroll down by users.

Comment: this might be what you are looking after : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294692/form-submits-twice-when-pressing-return-enter

Comment: if you are still having problems can you update your question and add the ksb and ksb_comments_details functions.

Comment: @ Tasos, I could not get your point.

Comment: Can you post your HTML code as well?